# Is it possible to import a module using a string in python?

Tags: python, try-except

Is there any chance to use the snippets given below? When I run this code, it returns "module  pandas  is not installed"

```
a = "pandas"

try:
    import a
    print("module ",a," is installed")
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    print("module ",a," is not installed")
```

But when I run the code given below:

```
try:
    import pandas
    print("module pandas is installed")
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    print("module pandas is not installed")
```

It returns "module pandas is installed".

What is the difference between them?

Comment: You probably want `eval("import %s" % a)` in first snippet.

Comment: try this without try and you will understand the difference. 
    a = "pandas"
    import a   . the error will be "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'a'"

Comment: Your title is not the same question as your body. Please fix.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, what you're doing is more equivalent to the following:

```
try:
    import "pandas"
    print("module ",a," is installed")
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    print("module ",a," is not installed")
```

You can't import a string, unless you use `importlib`. You can find documentation for that library [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html). That would look something like the following:

```
import importlib

a = "pandas"

try:
    globals()[a] = importlib.import_module(a)
    print("module ",a," is installed")
except:
    print("module ",a," is not installed")
```

Comment: `__import__(a, globals(), locals(), []))` also works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute the script as one combined formatted string, using `exec()`, this actually executes the script:

```
a = "pandas"

try:
    exec(f'import {a}')
    print("module ",a," is installed")
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    print("module ",a," is not installed")
```

To read more about the `Python` `exec()` function, visit:

> https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_exec.asp

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you import a module named `a` (you cannot use variables in an `import` statement), which results in `ModuleNotFoundError`. In your second example, you import a module named `pandas`.

If you want to dynamically import a module (e.g. based on user input), use `importlib`:

```py
import importlib

name = 'pandas'
try:
    module = importlib.import_module(name)
    print(f'Module {name} is installed')
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    print(f'Module {name} is not installed')
```

Do not use `eval` or `exec` - they are not safe.

Answer (score 0):

[@Jaz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65976337/2988730) has successfully shown what is wrong with your first approach. You can't import a module by variable name using the `import` statement.

In general, python philosophy is to ask for forgiveness, not permission. So you often see the following construction in common modules that have optional dependencies:

```
try:
    import pandas
except ImportError:
    print("pandas is not installed")
else:
    print("pandas is installed")
```

The programmatic interface to the `import` statement is the built-in [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) function. You can use it something like this:

```
m = 'pandas'
try:
    locals()[m] = __import__(m)
except ImportError:
    ...
```

A simplified interface is available in the functions of `importlib`.